# Troubles with array of objects interface in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array which is state entry that I populate in `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook, and it is quite simple:

```
state{
      array:[{a:0,b:0},{a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:2}]
     }
```

When I try to access it, however I am always getting an error:

`Property 'a' does not exist on type 'never'.`

I think I am having troubles with declaring an interface here, can't find a proper way to do that.
Something like this would probably do:

```
interface IState{
     array: object[]
}
```

Full version of component :

```
import * as React from "react";
import phrasalVerbs from "../data/phrasalVerbs";

interface IAnswerOptions {
   pVerb: string;
   meaning: string;
 }

interface IState {
  pVerbs: object;
  progress: number;
  answerOptions: IAnswerOptions[];
}

class PhrasalVerbs extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
  public state = {
    pVerbs: phrasalVerbs,
    progress: 0,
    answerOptions: []
  };

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.randomVariants();
  }

  public randomVariants = () => {
    let randomVariants: any[] = [];
    const currentVerbs = this.state.pVerbs.data;
    const shuffledVerbs = currentVerbs
      .map(a => [Math.random(), a])
      .sort((a: any, b: any): any => a[0] - b[0])
      .map(a => a[1]);
    randomVariants = [shuffledVerbs[0], shuffledVerbs[1], shuffledVerbs[2]];
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      answerOptions: randomVariants
    });
  };

  public render() {
    const { pVerbs, progress } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{pVerbs.data[progress].pVerb}</div>
        {/* <div>
          {this.state.answerOptions
            ? this.state.answerOptions[0].meaning
            : null}
        </div> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PhrasalVerbs;
```

Comment: Your objects aren't really valid.  Two properties named `c`?

Comment: My bad, did that by mistake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a type for your object:

```
interface IMyObject {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

interface IState {
    array: IMyObject[];
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<any, IState> {
    state = {
        array:[{a:0,b:0},{a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:2}]
    };

    render() {
        // should be OK
        const firstA: number = this.state.array[0].a;

        return <h1>{firstA}</h1>;
    }
}
```

Edit: looking into your code, it appears you’ve accidentally overridden the type of `state`. Typescript will automatically (and sometimes unhelpfully) allow you to override the types of fields in classes, so although you have your Component defined in terms of IState, the internal `state` property’s type is defined by the default value you gave it.

In this situation, an empty array has an inferred type of `never[]`, so you end up with an array whose elements you can’t use.

Comment: Still does not work, for some reason. If I do it by declaring state in the `state` object it is working fine, but using `componentDidMount` breaks everything

Comment: Even if I use `:any` when declaring a type for my array in interface it's not working

Comment: Please post the full version of your React component within your original post.

Comment: Done, if you need something else, feel free to ask! The commented code is the one that produces error.

Comment: Try going `public state: IState = { ... }`, you might be falling victim to type overriding.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Do you mind explaining it shortly in your answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Done! Good to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm did you setup strictPropertyInitialization in tsconfig?

Comment: Nope, and this problem is driving me crazy already. Maybe there is at least some workaround?