# Property Does Not Exist on Type 'Never' Typescript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm getting a 'Property 'activationDate' does not exist on type 'never'' error when I try to run my code in React, what would be the issue? I'm sure it relates to Typescript.

Edit: Still having issues with the mentor type being any? not sure what this means?

2nd Edit: FOR REFERENCE i'm following this tutorial (https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/) to make a simple GET request, I just don't know how to convert it to typescript.

```
const TOKEN_KEY:string = `mpp-tk`;

type mentor = { activationDate: any }


class SamSearch extends React.Component<any>  {

  public state = {
    mentors: mentor[] // or any[]
  }

public componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization : token
    }
  }

axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/findMentorFromSam/001339159`, config)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
    const mentors = res.data;
    this.setState({ mentors });
  })


 }



public render(): React.ReactNode {
    const {
      classes
    } = this.props as any & {
      titleComponent?: React.Component
    };
return (

  <Grid container className={classes.test}>
  <ul>
  { this.state.mentors.map(mentor => <li>{mentor.activationDate}</li>)}
  </ul>
  <p>TEST</p>
  </Grid>



   )
  }
}
export default compose(
  withRouter,
  withStyles(styles)
)(SamSearch)
```

Comment: Can you show the mentor type definition, and what the activationDate is supposed to be as well (if it is a custom type), I suspect somehow one of the mentors elements is of type NEVER that doesn't have the activationDate element on it?

Comment: Can you post the entirety of your React component? 

It might be related to this depending on how you initialized `state`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52655185/643919

Comment: Have you confirmed that `mentor.activationDate` is definitely being set?

Comment: updated w/  component

Comment: component cleaned up and updated.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to say what type the array mentor is, it should be something like

```
type Mentor = { activationDate: any }

class SamSearch extends React.Component<any>  {
  public state: { mentors: Mentor[] } = { // or any[]
    mentors: []
  }
  // ...rest of the class
}
```

Comment: i'm confused on where this goes? I put it in the SamSearch class above the public componentDidMount() function, but i'm getting 'An element access should take an argument'?

Comment: well, the type Mentor ... should be out of the class definition

Comment: still a nogo. i added the type mentor, in the changes above. getting a couple of error messages. 1. mentor only refers to a type, but is being used as a value. 2. mentor implicity has a 'any' type. 3.missing key prop for element.

Answer (score 2):

```
public state = {
    mentors: mentor[] // or any[]
}
```

This is not valid TypeScript - you can't declare types within object literal. Valid way would be:

```
public state: { mentors: mentor[] } = {
    mentors: []
}
```

However if you take React into consideration, this is also wrong way and reason why you're getting `never` - you should use second generic parameter of `React.Component<TProps, TState>` and set default state like this:

```
type SamSearchProps = {};
interface SamSearchState {
    mentors: mentor[];
}
class SamSearch extends React.Component<SamSearchProps, SamSearchState> {
    constructor(props: SamSearchProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { mentors: [] };
    }

    ~rest of component logic~
}
```

Comment: still getting error in the interface SamSearchProps {} 1. an empty literal is equivalent to {},  and in interface SamSearchState {} 1.cannot find name 'mentor'

Comment: The first issue should be fixed I think. The name `mentor` is whatever your mentor type is, so in your case `type mentor = { activationDate: any }`

Comment: Check out this link for more complete sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/n3893jvz0l

Answer (score -1):

This could be caused by your typescript settings. If you have `strict` option set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`, it means it will check types more, well, strictly :) You have to explicitly check if `this.state.mentors` are not empty or `null`.

Also, you can specify Props of Component by writing `type Props = {/*props here*/}`, then applying it to the class declaration `class SamSearch extends React.Component<Props>`, so you can avoid crazy stuff like 

`const {
      classes
    } = this.props 
    /* Not needed anymore: 
      as any & {
      titleComponent?: React.Component
    }; */`